# Proof of Second Bianchi Identity

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, connections

I am reading ch 7 of *Geometry, Topology, and Physics* by Mikio Nakahara. And I am trying to understand how to prove the second Bianchi identity:
$$
\left(\nabla_X R\right)(Y, Z) V+\left(\nabla_Z R\right)(X, Y) V+\left(\nabla_Y R\right)(Z, X) V=0
$$

In his approach, the symmetrizer is defined as
$$
\mathfrak{S}\{f(X, Y, Z)\}=f(X, Y, Z)+f(Z, X, Y)+f(Y, Z, X)
$$
Since the assumption is torsion-free connection:
$$
T(X, Y)=\nabla_X Y-\nabla_Y X-[X, Y]=0
$$
we have $$R(T(X,Y),Z)V = 0$$ and $$\mathfrak{S}(R(T(X,Y),Z))) = 0$$
Equation (7.82) on the book:
$$
\begin{aligned}
0 &=\mathfrak{S}\left\{R\left(\nabla_X Y, Z\right)-R\left(\nabla_Y X, Z\right)-R([X, Y], Z)\right\} V \\
&=\mathfrak{S}\left\{R\left(\nabla_Z X, Y\right)+R\left(X, \nabla_Z Y\right)-R([X, Y], Z)\right\} V .
\end{aligned}
$$

I failed to understand how the first equality lead to the second equality in equation (7.82).

Any suggestions? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Because $\mathfrak S\{f(X,Y,Z)\} = \mathfrak S\{f(Z,X,Y)\}$ and $R(Z,W) = -R(W,Z)$. By the way, your "i.e." should be "we have" (torsion zero implies the two equations, but not necessarily vice versa).

Comment: Thanks! I figured out how the symmetrizer works here. Should I delete this question?

Comment: It might help someone else. But turn my comment and your figuring into an answer.

Comment: Yes, keep the question and post an answer. This question arises quite often.